# Converting string input to DateTime within condition list of numpy.select

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am using user input (strings) to find matching conditions in an EXCEL file via `numpy.select()`.

One of my conditions captures dates (mainly years YYYY) entered by the user to check which data in the `event_start` column of my EXCEL file (read into a `pandas.DataFrame`) fall into that time range:

```
pd.to_datetime(exy[0]) <= pd.to_datetime(f['event_start']) <= pd.to_datetime(exy[1])
```

In this case, `exy` is a list of two dates entered by the user. These two dates define the date range to which time information retrieved from the indicated `pandas.DataFrame` column ought to be compared.

However, this condition does not return any results. Converting to datetime within a condition list is not possible because `f['event_start']` essentially constitutes a series and not an individual value.

How can I convert individual values while preserving the overall relation to other values in the array?

I have tried list comprehension within the condition list, with `len(pers_f)` being the number of rows in the original file:

```
pd.to_datetime(exy[0]) <= pd.to_datetime([f['event_start'].iloc[n] for n in range(0, len(pers_f))]) <= pd.to_datetime(exy[1])
```

But this does not trigger the correct output either.

What is the recommended procedure for working with dates in condition lists for `numpy.select()`?

Comment: what do you mean by "*in an EXCEL file*"? did you load the data from that file to some data structure, e.g. a pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, it is a pandas.DataFrame.

Comment: I figured out that one major issue in my data is that I am frequently going back before 1700. See this GITHUB issue: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1867

Answer (score 0):

My script had two basic issues:

1. The dates I was trying to convert the `Datetime` were often dates before 1700 and thus not suitable for working with `pd.to_datetime` in the first place.
2. I was not able to perform list comprehension within the `numpy.select()` condition list.

This is why I have a) resorted to `pandas.Period` instead and b) created a work-around to handle dates outside the condition list.

Dates entered by the user are immediately converted to periods:

```
try:
    d1=pd.Period(exy[0], freq="D") # convert input to Period with day frequence
    print(type(d1))

    d2=pd.Period(exy[1], freq="D") # convert input to Period with day frequence
    print(type(d2))
    
except IndexError:
    pass
```

If the user has selected a date range of two dates to find all matching dates in between, the following operation is performed:

```
print("Searching for date range between", d1, "and", d2, "!") 
        for n in range(0, len(pers_f)):
            try:
                if d1 <= pd.Period(f['event_start'].iloc[n]) <= d2:
                    nf=nf.append(f.iloc[n]) # create new data frame
            except ValueError as error:
                print(error.args)
                pass
            
# define possible conditions and choices
        
        try:
            condlist = [(nf['pers_name'].str.contains('|'.join(qn)) ^ nf['pers_name'].isin(qn)),
                nf['inst_name'].isin(qi), 
                nf['pers_title'].isin(qt),
                nf['pers_function'].isin(qf),
                nf['rel_pers'].str.contains('|'.join(qr)) ^ nf['rel_pers'].isin(qr)]
    
            choicelist = [nf['pers_name'],
                nf['inst_name'], 
                nf['pers_title'],
                nf['pers_function'],
                nf['rel_pers']]
            
        except:
            print("No match found!")
```

The results I get are fine, but the script seems unnecessarily convoluted. I will be grateful if someone can still suggest a more elegant solution.